# pyodbc: print datatype in python

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I got into pyodbc. I would like to print the datatypes of the columns just once above the actual data. But right now, it prints the datatypes through the whole loop or the program shuts down. I'm not sure about what exactly my mistake is.

```
def selectPlace(dbc):
cursor = dbc.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nr, address from Place')
except:
    print ('Error')
    cursor.close()
    return
 
print ('\nPlaces:')
i = 0
for row in cursor:
    if i == 0:
         print('Datatypes: ', type(row[0]), type(row[1]))
         i = 1
    print (row[0], row[1])
  #  print type(row[0])        

cursor.close()

x = input('Input : ')

return x
```

Comment: I guess cursors aren't available after it used, means print data type will work but,  print (row[0], row[1])   won't work  // cursor loose the value after it print data type. Use some thing other than cursor which preserve data

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! It works now. I'm still using the cursor. But I had a syntax error at "i == 0"